# Not able to handle multiple request by Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to send multiple json object in one request , but I am not able to extract values from it.

```
def config(request):
print "type",type(request)
print "request in config",request.body
  if request.method == 'POST':
    print "In Handler"
    print "Request Body is ",request.body
    data =  simplejson.loads(request.body)
    for i in data:
        print "REQUEST is ____",i
        z = json.dumps(i)
        rew = retResp(z)
    proID = request.data["proId"]
```

For request 1 can find proID but for request 2 I am not able to get proID.

```
req1 = curl -X POST http://192.168.2.242:8080/server/config/ -d '{"confMsgReqId": 2,"proId":"123"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
req2 = curl -X POST http://192.168.2.242:8080/server/config/ -d '[{"confMsgReqId": 2,"proId":"123"},{"confMsgReqId": 2,"proId":"345"}]' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in the first request is a dictionary, so you can access `data['proID']`.

The data in the second request is a list of two dictionaries, so you can access `data[0]['proID']` or `data[1]['proID']`.

You'll find it easier if you use an array for the first request as well as the second. It's possible to make an api that can handle a single element of a list, but it makes the code more complicated.

```
req1 = curl -X POST http://192.168.2.242:8080/server/config/ -d '[{"confMsgReqId": 2,"proId":"123"}]' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Looking at your code, you might want to access the id inside the loop. It's not clear why you are decoding the json manually instead of using `request.data`.

```
for d in request.data:
      d["proId"]
```

Comment: earlier I was handling only 1 request at a time with using request.data["element"] , and for this project I use this (request.data["element"]) method everywhere .  So , Do I need to change everywhere in my project . I mean can't I made two new request (dictionary)

Comment: Now able to done the changes, Thanks  @alasdair ,sorry I misinterpreted your point.